# Is $f(g)$ a PRG if $f$ is a OWF and $g$ a PRG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

If we have a PRG $g$ and a OWF $f$, can we say that $g' = f(g)$ is a PRG?

And what if $g$ stretches its input by a factor of 2?

Comment: Note that a PRG requires a random input, something which an OWF does not guarantee for its output.

Comment: @SEJPM: Isn't the PRG applied before the OWF according to the question?

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer oh yeah, I miss-read that one. Then the answer should actually be easier: Can you come up with an OWF that doesn't have randomly looking output (potentially given another OWF)?

Comment: @SEJPM, what I was thinking was that a OWF can actually reduce the search space, for example, receiving natural numbers and spitting out even numbers in some, hard to invert, way. But if that's the case, then we would have an advantage when trying to decide if a given y came from f(g) or not. Is this logic correct?

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer sorry, I was unclear, the question was not addressed at you but at J. Dionisio for them to get a lead in the right direction, as I didn't want to spoil the solution ;)

Comment: @J.Dionisio ok, now I'm confused. Do you suggest to apply the OWF the input and then on the OWF output a PRG or first apply a PRG and then an OWF (in your question post)?

Comment: @SEJPM, the question is about applying a PRG and then a OWF and deciding if that is a PRG. What I was suggesting was that, even if the input of a OWF is random, its output may not be, since the image of a OWF can be smaller than the co-domain. And so the image of f wouldn't pass as random, as we could make an educated guess as to an element from the codomain came from f or not.

Comment: @J.Dionisio correct

Comment: @SEJPM, alright thank you for spending the time to help me! :)